# Please help me find a question

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I am almost certain I've seen a question on main site that asked what SW Stormtrooper armor was made of.

I finally tracked down the answer.

But I can't find the question anymore. None of my searches yield results. **Help please!**

I'll post a new one if I'm just hallucinating, but I KNOW I saw one!

Comment: Can you exclude any? Show us what you've tried.

Comment: Did you search with Canadian/British spelling?  _armour_  I didn't see one that specifically asks what it's made of, but a few that are close...

Comment: @Mooz - searched for various combinations of "armor", "material" with SW/EP7 tags

Comment: Related: [What was the point of the Stormtroopers' armour in Star Wars?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/38509/21267) and [Is stormtrooper armor not very strong or were the rebel guns just that powerful?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/14454/21267) and [Are Stormtroopers' armor ineffective against Stormtrooper blasters?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/112277/21267)

Comment: All I found were the 3 Mooz drug up; maybe it's been deleted?

Comment: @Mike Mmmm, I love drugging up those questions.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield - hm. if so, I'm SOL searching. Good point. It's neither of the 3 Mooz listed (or Megha in the answer).

Comment: @Mooz - Kids, don't do drugs!

Comment: @DVK - you're not the boss of kids!

Comment: Is it [Did anyone in the Star Wars universe wear effective armour?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/107832/21267) or [Is Vader's armor lightsaber-proof?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/54924/21267) or [Why do Stormtroopers wear white?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/51362/21267)?

Comment: If there is a record of searches on the main site somewhere, it is going to be a list of variations on Star Wars/Stormtroopers/Armor for the next couple of hours.

Comment: Could you be conflating SW with Iron Man somehow?  http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/81863/what-material-is-iron-mans-armor-made-of

Comment: I'll try another angle; what does you answer entail? (You don't have to reveal your answer, just like: will it contain info about the armour *meterial* or *technical specs*?)...

Comment: I may have a solution - I'll ask, and we'll see if it gets closed as a dupe.

Comment: @WadCheber - LOL worth a try, thanks! Worst case scenario, you get dupe-disappointment, best case, you win the NHQ lottery and repcap from just one question :)

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114846/what-is-stormtrooper-armor-made-of

Answer (score 2):

Might it be either [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112277/are-stormtroopers-armor-ineffective-against-stormtrooper-blasters) or [this other one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14454/is-stormtrooper-armor-not-very-strong-or-were-the-rebel-guns-just-that-powerful)?

The questions seem focused on the armor's effectiveness, but a question on the construction material might be asked, or speculated on, or even just relevant, to determining how effective the armor is or should be.

I don't think I saw any ones that are a better fit than this, sorry.

Comment: No, sorry, neither of those two. The one I recall was explicitly "what is it made of" kind.

Comment: @DVK - It would be nice if it were that easy.  Well, good luck finding it.